# Нужна помощь с парсингом данных с сайта при помощи Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time




url = 'https://obnovi-oboi.ru/goods?category=oboi'
opts = Options()
#opts.add_argument("--headless")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts)

browser.get(url)
html = browser.find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME, value='html')
for i in range(4):
    html.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
time.sleep(2)
xpath = '/html/body/main/section/div/div[2]/button'
browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath).click()

time.sleep(3)
container = browser.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="row items")
oboi_items = container.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, value="card good-item")#Тут уже  много что попробовал...


browser.quit()
```

Тут код парсера , ссылка на [сайт](https://obnovi-oboi.ru/goods?category=oboi) откуда я хочу взять картинку , цену и название обоев.
Прошу помочь, что я делаю не так?!

Answer (score 0):

В этих строках ошибка:

```
container = browser.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="row items")
oboi_items = container.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, value="card good-item")#Тут уже  много что попробовал...
```

В Selenium с помощью локатора `By.CLASS_NAME` нельзя искать составные классы (в вашем случае это `row items`). Это описано в [официальной документации](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/#:%7E:text=compound%20class%20names%20are%20not%20permitted). Т. е. вы можете искать или по `row` или по `items`, но не оба класса одновременно.

Попробуйте переписать локаторы на XPATH или CSS Selectors.